# Access Amazon Alexa ShoppingList via REST API in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I want to access my Alexa internal shoppinglist in C#.

I've read every documentation I can find, but don't get it to work properly.

I just want to access the list for a server internal sync tool I'm building.

My current code:

```cs
private async Task<AlexaAuthResponse> GetAlexaToken()
{
    var endpointUri = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token";

    var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"));
    nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "amzn1.application-oa2-client.924096ecd9d542cdb5XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
    nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "amzn1.oa2-cs.v1.15db95e13a90827b693510fbfa68f709f14b5a7285651d0eXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
    nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "alexa:skill_messaging"));

    using var authRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpointUri);
    authRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc);
    var authResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(authRequest);

    using var graphResponseJson = JsonDocument.Parse(await authResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    var serializedJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(graphResponseJson, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping });

    return AlexaAuthResponse.GetSingleResultFromJson(serializedJson);
}
```

I'm getting an access token with this:

```cs
private async void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var auth = await GetAlexaToken();

    var apiUri = "https://api.amazonalexa.com/v2/householdlists/";

    using var graphRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUri);
    graphRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", auth.access_token);
    graphRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json;masked=false");
    var graphResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(graphRequest);


    using var graphResponseJson = JsonDocument.Parse(await graphResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    var serializedJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(graphResponseJson, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping });
}
```

Calling the householdlists REST API just returns:

> "500 internal server error".

In my custom Alexa skill, I've granted every possible access to the lists!

1. How can I get the required userId from my skill?
2. How can I get the required consent token, to ask my skill, to return all shoppinglists?

I can't find any working example. everything is so old and clustered everywhere...